# Перевод даты из MySQL в MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Вопрос закрыт!!!
Проблема в исходных данных. При конвертации в базу MS SQL Server числа были урезаны!!!

Получили базу данных MS SQL, которая была конвертирована из MySQL базы. Одно из полей хранит дату. в MySQL поле объявлено как bigint (200). 
Не могу перевести числовые значения в дату.

Вот примеры числовых данных и представленные ими даты:

```
-1654915712 => 20.02.66
-341269120  => 23.11.1948
 165928320  => 19.11.63
```

Пробовал так:

```
Declare @date As Datetime2 = '1970-01-01'
Select  @date, DateAdd(s, -341269120, @date)
```

Получаю неверные даты.

Как получить правильные значения?

Comment: А почему '1970-01-01', а не '1900-01-01'? Ну а вообще, для корректного перевода надо спросить у того кто пилил MySQL, что это за значения.

Comment: Потому что некоторые типы данных опираются на эту дату. С датой 1900-01-01 тоже неверно :(. Кстати клиент был написан на яве. Какая GUI-библиотека использовалась, я не знаю. И спросить нe y кoгo

Comment: [Вот тут очень хорошо объяснено](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100683/1497923).

Comment: Не могу применить, не получается

Comment: Вопрос закрыт!!! Проблема в исходных данных. При конвертации в базу MS SQL Server числа были урезаны!!!